# In Dune could anyone become a human-worm hybrid?

Tags: novel, dune, hybrid

I was wondering if only the Kwisatz Haderach could interact with sand trout and become a human-worm hybrid or could anyone do it?  I don't remember the process that Leto had to go through to become a hybrid very well.

Comment: At minimum you need a massive tolerance to the Water of Life.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**No**. Only someone with prescience, the experience of past lives, and total control over their metabolism could have become a worm-human hybrid.

> No sandtrout had ever before encountered a hand such as this 
>   one, every cell supersaturated with spice. No other human had ever before lived and reasoned in such a condition. Delicately Leto **adjusted his enzyme balance**, drawing on the **illuminated sureness he'd gained in spice trance**. The **knowledge from those uncounted lifetimes which blended themselves within him** provided the certainty through which he chose the precise adjustments, slaving off the death from an overdose which would engulf him if he relaxed his watchfulness for only a heartbeat. And at the same time he blended himself with the sandtrout, feeding on it, feeding it, learning it. **His trance vision provided the template and he followed it precisely.** (Children of Dune)

For normal people, the sandtrout-glove would simply slip off after a while:

> For a moment, though, he'd felt the reality of his terrible decision. The 
>   sandtrout glove. It was the play of children. If one held a sandtrout in the 
>   hand, smoothing it over your skin, it formed a living glove. Traces of blood in 
>   the skin's capillaries could be sensed by the creatures, but something mingled 
>   with the blood's water repelled them. Sooner or later, the glove would slip off 
>   into the sand, there to be lifted into a spice-fiber basket. The spice soothed 
>   them until they were dumped into the deathstill.
>   (Children of Dune)

Comment: Leto II told Siona that she could do it because she was an Atreides, indicating that a certain peculiarity of their genetics was required as well.

Comment: @Omegacron, absolutely true.  Also, Paul Atreides could have done it as well.  Leto in his journals:  I began this account in the first year of my stewardship, in the first throes of my metamorphosis when I was still mostly human, even visibly so. The sandtrout skin which I accepted (and my father refused) which gave me greatly amplified strength plus virtual immunity from conventional attack and aging-that skin still covered a form recognizably human: two legs, two arms, a human face
framed in the scrolled folds of the sandtrout.